# Replace NA with factor in one dataframe based on grouping variable and date from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, match, na

I am working with two different data frames which are structured differently but contain the same information. Here is the first mock dataframe:-

```
UserId<-c("n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", 
          "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", 
          "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", 
          "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", 
          "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", 
          "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", 
          "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", 
          "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", 
          "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", 
          "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", 
          "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", 
          "i95C1a", "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", 
          "iX45wN", "n4RhHC", "k6qjRM", "nPUYOw", "Bm77mQ", "i95C1a", "iX45wN"
)


eventDateTime<-structure(c(1420081869.97425, 1420172875.75246, 1420267947.2653, 
                           1420368834.57653, 1420424712.65942, 1420541210.43439, 1420629609.9716, 
                           1420703746.46464, 1420788777.7267, 1420850669.16688, 1420943298.10164, 
                           1421028427.25171, 1421136879.38698, 1421210193.28063, 1421313257.14934, 
                           1421387900.60726, 1421483801.11956, 1421582050.3433, 1421642017.51975, 
                           1421745585.63356, 1421838779.26598, 1421893964.55692, 1421999352.30669, 
                           1422063023.98015, 1422155543.93289, 1422247080.1288, 1422317378.46239, 
                           1422419719.15975, 1422527170.64454, 1422590703.07666, 1422683225.86099, 
                           1422774701.24366, 1422856520.98446, 1422929644.60038, 1423043742.52736, 
                           1423123277.76309, 1423215111.16198, 1423271863.16464, 1423384864.31287, 
                           1423457767.05536, 1423561864.87991, 1423640753.00037, 1423733022.69533, 
                           1423809491.16866, 1423894883.88586, 1423992500.18921, 1424045807.90794, 
                           1424151816.33881, 1424249235.95351, 1424333926.00324, 1424411033.16768, 
                           1424514004.2494, 1424582125.79503, 1424660175.24237, 1424739053.33484, 
                           1424826696.93812, 1424922462.93775, 1425017605.00017, 1425110198.6193, 
                           1425185575.06409, 1425293836.23993, 1425353483.6657, 1425447031.63937, 
                           1425527959.44992, 1425628117.60418, 1425697546.32493, 1425793473.15473, 
                           1425892304.62097, 1425949239.4667, 1426069813.88146, 1426133047.95091, 
                           1426241063.82313, 1426306176.72673, 1426392019.07701, 1426484578.37379, 
                           1426588942.96811, 1426674139.46513, 1426740047.54828, 1426843180.25419, 
                           1426937498.69748, 1427001177.28974, 1427099580.63412, 1427172479.75674, 
                           1427255655.21296, 1427360706.16479, 1427423156.30542, 1427531520.43681, 
                           1427592457.09099, 1427684205.1038, 1427766190.74919), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                           "POSIXt"), tzone = "")

eventOutcome<-structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                          1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
                          2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
                          1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
                          3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
                          3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Outcome_A", 
                                                                                          "Outcome_B", "Outcome_C", "Outcome_D"), class = c("variable", 
                                                                                                                                            "factor"), varname = "Factor")
df<-data.frame(UserId,eventDateTime,eventOutcome)
df<-df%>%arrange(UserId,eventDateTime)


head(df)
#  UserId       eventDateTime eventOutcome
#1 Bm77mQ 2015-01-04 10:53:54    Outcome_D
#2 Bm77mQ 2015-01-10 00:44:29    Outcome_A
#3 Bm77mQ 2015-01-16 05:58:20    Outcome_A
#4 Bm77mQ 2015-01-22 02:32:44    Outcome_C
#5 Bm77mQ 2015-01-28 04:35:19    Outcome_C
#6 Bm77mQ 2015-02-03 02:14:04    Outcome_C
```

And here is the other dataframe:-

```
UserId<-c("n4RhHC","n4RhHC","n4RhHC","nPUYOw","nPUYOw","nPUYOw","iX45wN","iX45wN","iX45wN")

Firstime<-c("2015-01-01 03:11:09","2015-01-19 04:33:37","2015-02-18 08:47:15",
            "2015-01-21 11:12:59","2015-02-08 08:41:04","2015-03-04 05:30:31",   
            "2015-01-12 02:07:07","2015-02-05 08:01:17","2015-03-01 04:52:55")

Lasttime<-c("2015-01-13 08:14:39","2015-02-06 09:31:51","2015-02-24 00:50:53",
            "2015-02-02 05:55:20","2015-02-26 03:47:42","2015-03-16 05:42:58",
            "2015-01-24 01:30:23","2015-02-17 05:43:36","2015-03-13 10:04:23")

eventOutcome<-c("Outcome_D",NA, "Outcome_A",NA,NA,"Outcome_A","Outcome_B","Outcome_B",NA)



df2<-data.frame(UserId,Firstime,Lasttime,eventOutcome)

df2$Firstime<-lubridate::ymd_hms(df2$Firstime)
df2$Lasttime<-lubridate::ymd_hms(df2$Lasttime)


head(df2)
  UserId            Firstime            Lasttime eventOutcome
#1 n4RhHC 2015-01-01 03:11:09 2015-01-13 08:14:39    Outcome_D
#2 n4RhHC 2015-01-19 04:33:37 2015-02-06 09:31:51         <NA>
#3 n4RhHC 2015-02-18 08:47:15 2015-02-24 00:50:53    Outcome_A
#4 nPUYOw 2015-01-21 11:12:59 2015-02-02 05:55:20         <NA>
#5 nPUYOw 2015-02-08 08:41:04 2015-02-26 03:47:42         <NA>
#6 nPUYOw 2015-03-04 05:30:31 2015-03-16 05:42:58    Outcome_A
```

As you can see, there are NA entries in df2 and I want to replace these with the information in df. How can I populate the NA fields in df2 with the corresponding eventOutcome in df, based on UserId and the corresponding time entry in Lasttime column that also is the matched time entry in eventDateTime?

For instance, the first NA field in df2 would be replaced with "Outcome_A", the second NA field would be "Outcome_C" and so on. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The Lasttime doesn't exactly matchh the value in other data column

Comment: @akrun How do you mean? I have eyeballed both dataframes and the values seem the same. Can you illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I tried `df2 %>% left_join(df, by = c("UserId", Lasttime = "eventDateTime"))` and it is not getting matches in `eventOutcome.y`.  I converted `df2$Lasttime <- as.POSIXct(df2$Lasttime)`

Comment: I see. I think in df2 the datetime stamps might be in character format. I will amend my question

Comment: I think the reason could be that there may be second difference in the time stamps

Comment: I don't think it is that (all due respect :) ). I have amended the code. Would it be worth trying your solution again?

Comment: I still not getting any matches

Comment: You can check `sum(df$eventDateTime %in% df2$Lasttime)#[1] 0`

Comment: Hmm I see, this is really strange. I will try and come up with a work around here.